# railstutorial.org chapter 8 accessing remember_digest of the user database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

in Chapter 8
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#code-log_in_with_remember

there is a code in app/models/user.rb

```
 # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end
```

How is it possible to access **remember_digest** directly like that? Is it because **user.rb** is a model and we can access all it's fields directly? is it same thing as self.remember_digest ?

Comment: Yes, that's just Ruby though `method_name` and `self.method_name` act the same (ignoring the differences between private and public methods.

Comment: remember_digest is not a method though.. it's just a field in the database..

Comment: I'm assuming it's a column on the users table, in which case Rails, specifically ActiveRecord, creates a method for it on the model. That's one of the benefits of using rails, boiler plate like that is done automagically. How it does it is most likely some metaprogramming. I'd assume `define_method`.

Comment: @MCB hm interesting! So if you wanted to define your own method and reference a column on users table, what is the specific syntax you would use? Let's say column user_description